# PHP cURL no way on this specific URL

Tags: php, curl

I find no way to PHP cURL this URL :

http://www.bvger.ch/publiws/pub/cache.jsf?displayName=A-1695/2006&decisionDate=2007-02-27

Can any of you help me ? I tried many ways without any success. For example :

```
    FUNCTION get_data2($url) 
{ 
  $curl = curl_init(); 
  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
  $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/bot.html'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
  $html = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command 
  curl_close($curl); // close the connection 
  return $html; // and finally, return $html 
}
```

OR

```
FUNCTION get_data1($url) 
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

Both return nothing echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me...

```
function get_data2($url) 
{ 
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"; 
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"; 
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/bot.html'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
    $html = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command 
    curl_close($curl); // close the connection 
    return $html; // and finally, return $html 
}

$url = 'http://www.bvger.ch/publiws/pub/cache.jsf?displayName=A-1695/2006&decisionDate=2007-02-27';

echo get_data2($url);
```

Don't capitalize "function". Also you must have been cut-n-pasting and didn't correct one of the lines to match the others using $curl instead of $ch.

Comment: Thank you for helping a beginner.